# How to change the comments form title based on post type

Tags: custom-post-types, comments

I know how to change the title of the comment form by using `comment_form_defaults`, but I don't know how to make it different for a custom post type from a regular post. Also I would like to have the verbiage different in my comments.php file. Is it possible to have the comments.php file different for a custom post type, like you can do the header and footer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `comment_form_defaults` filter to change your text based on custom post type.  Just check the post type in your filter function.

For example:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'my_comment_form_defaults' );
function my_comment_form_defaults( $defaults ) {

     if ( 'my_cool_custom_post_type' == get_post_type() ) {

          $defaults['title_reply'] == 'My Custom Post Type Comment Title';
     }
     return $defaults;
}
```

If you need to change various elements of the defaults, see where `$defaults` is defined just before the filter hook is applied in the source here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.1/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L2429

Rather than load a different comments.php based on post type, you could potentially use some `switch()` or `if()` logic based on `get_post_type()` to display differently based on the requested post type.

Comment: This looks exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Glad that was helpful.  If this answers your question, would you please mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by butlerblog is correct. Just a small correction. (As I dont have the reputation to comment, I am posting it as my answer.)

The following line

> $defaults['title_reply'] == 'My Custom Post Type Comment Title';

should be:

> $defaults['title_reply'] = 'My Custom Post Type Comment Title';

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, you will be able to post comments.